# Common Code Convention for not equal in conditional statements

Tags: c#, conditional-statements, coding-style

I've been coming across not equal `!=` or `!condition` in conditional statements ever since I started programming. Maybe it's because my brain is pre-conditioned in the English language to overthink multiple negation. But I have been wondering, is there a common development community accepted practice when it comes to evaluating for true in conditional statements? Or rather, the way I see it sometimes: evaluating for not false.

Maybe there are exceptions where `!=` cannot be completely unavoidable?

For Example:

This might be a very simple and trivial, but is this preferred

```
string myStringVar = "dogs";


if (myStringVar != "dogs") //In my mind, "False this is not true"
{
     //code
}
else if (myStringVar != cats) //In my mind, "True this is false"
{
     //code
}
```

Or is this preferable

```
if (myStringVar == "dogs")
{
     //"True"
}
else if (myStringVar == "cats")
{
     //"False"
}
```

Then there's

```
bool MyBoolMethod()
{
     return false;
}


if (!MyBoolMethod()) // True this method does not return true
{
     //code
}
```

This is a very trivial and simplified example, I just want to know how to write readable, maintainable code. Does anyone else have a somewhat difficult time reading conditionals like this or is it just me?

Comment: I read `(myStringVar != "dogs")` as `myStringVar` is not equal to `"dogs"`. Which is to say that that conditional should not be a problem.

Comment: And maybe that's my problem; that, sometimes while debugging or writing out code, I imagine the variable to be assigned. In more complex situations, I seem to get confused with `not equal` versus `equal`

Comment: The first if-else-if construct above is definitely poor. That logic should check for specifics. The two branches of logic there could catch scenarios that would fall into both logical constructs. Checking for equality in that instance would definitely be better. It almost entirely depends on what you wish to do. You should definitely avoid double negation though e.g. having a boolean variable called `notFound` starting at true and then setting to false when you find the thing in question. It would be better to have a `found` variable which starts false and then set to true once found.

Answer (score 1):

"None of the above."

Since you're using `string`s, the assumption is that `myStringVar` can be anything. If I say:

```
string myStringVar = "Aardvark";
```

Then your first example, it will run the `myStringVar != "dogs"` section of code; In the second example, neither will be executed. So they're not equivalent pieces of code.

The only way they would be equivalent is if you were using Enums (in which case I would suggest using a `case` statement).

In your third example, it would depend on what `MyBoolMethod()` was named, and how easy it was to understand by a future coder. To use an example,

```
bool isDog()
{
  return false;
}
```

is is easy to understand. The question then becomes is

```
if(!isDog()) ...
```

more clear than

```
if(isNotDog()) ...
```

I would argue that the first is more clear than the second. There are other situations, however, where that is not the case.

Comment: I agree with writing method signatures that are meaningful. Then distinguishing the return value elsewhere in the code is clear. I think that my examples versus your examples prove that the coding conventions I need to really focus on are meaningful signatures and property names correct?

Comment: Yes. There are some very good books out on coding style, and I found them useful (though the one I'm thinking of is for Java, but I can't recall the name). I use the "six month" rule: "If I read my own code six months from now, will I understand it -- or will I ask what moron wrote it?"

Answer (score 1):

Equality and inequality are just something one needs to get comfortable with and choose in context. If the logical problem requires looking to test against equality use equality if it is looking to disqualify use inequality.

The readability and maintainability can be reinforced through good design as you started to allude to with your mybool method.

**Exmaple**

```cs
public class Animal
{
    public static Enum AnimalType
    {
         Dog,
         Cat
    }  

    private _animalType;

    public Animal(Enum AnimalType type)
    {
         AnimalType = _animalType;
    }

    public bool isOfType(Enum AnimalType type)
    {
        return _animalType == type ? true : false;
    }

}

public someothermethod()
{
    //doing inclusion
    If(MyAnmialObject.isOfType(Animal.AnimalType.Dog))
    {
        //if type matches
    }

    //Doing exclusion
    If(!MyAnmialObject.isOfType(Animal.AnimalType.Dog))
    {
        //if type does not match
    }
}
```

You still have to get used to inequality but you know it is checking for isOfType and the named type.

Comment: So many situations I've come across with `not equal` are so the developer avoids having to write an `else statement`. If I only wanted to do something when `MyAnimalObject` is not of type `Animal.AnimalType.Dog`, you think the best way to write the logic is to write a not equal if statement, rather than _if equals dog, do nothing. else execute my other animal code_ ?

Comment: If you are only doing something with the condition that the animal is not a dog why would you not just check for that? Checking for is a dog then handling the false condition in an else block just creates an if block with no code. If you always want to have the else you could look into the Ternary Operator.

Comment: Well maybe I should have added conditional operators as part of my question. You bring up a good point when you say "why would you not just check for that". I've edited other developers code where I've needed to add what would happen if it was a dog. At the time the code was written, they only needed to know what to do if it wasn't. So, I guess it's readable and maintainable. I was thinking about this for a while thinking I was doing something bass ackwards.

Comment: You can add the else on an exclusion just as easily as on an inclusion. I see no difference between the two the only important thing is whether or not it is clear that you are excluding or including. I could see how the else block would confuse someone if the if statement were hard to understand. Which is why my whole point is that one should make the if statement as clear as possible through design rather than worrying about whether the statement is inclusion or exclusion.